# Run an executable file from Caja

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, mate-desktop, nemo, caja

As a new Linux "superuser" trying to migrate from Windows 7 I have resisted asking basic questions that can be answered by searching, but I am stuck on this.

When I create an executable file from C with gcc in the Linux terminal, called say `hello.exe` it is given `X` permission. Then from the terminal I can run `./hello.exe` no problem.

But when I try to run it from Caja it just shows its components as a text file. I can, however, select "Run as administrator" but then I have to enter my login password.

This is irrespective of which of these two settings is enabled:

- Run executable text files when they are opened.
- View executable text files when they are opened.

I leave it as the second setting though, otherwise I get asked what I want to do every time I view or edit a text file.

I have tried to launch Caja from the terminal with `sudo caja` (needs password) but then, Caja won't run the executable  *at all* because the Run option is no longer there.

How can I run an executable from Caja directly: with a double-click?

---

Edit: Can you run an executable from *any* file manager with a simple double-click?

---

Edit 2: Now running Mint Cinnamon with Nemo file manager but the question is basically the same. Am I missing some setting that allows an executable to be run directly?

---

Edit 3:

During my research I found
[**GNOME Is Removing the Ability to Launch Binary Apps from Nautilus**](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/nautilus-remove-ability-launch-binaries-apps):

> "Or, to put it another way, you won’t be able to double-click on programs, scripts or apps to launch them using Nautilus." (*May 2018*)

And as I suspect that the file manager authors develop them as derivatives of open source code (or perhaps use common system components), perhaps none of them now do.

I also found this Wikipedia page [Comparison of file managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers) has various tables. The one called [File features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers#File_features) has the last column as "Run executable files" so I tried out several of those file managers.

- *None* of them would run an executable file which I have compiled (and some of them won't even allow easy access to my work drive – which is never the system drive).

But anyway, I have discovered an easy work-around for now, which is that my favourite text editor Geany will run an executable of the current source file, if it exists, from a single click or F5 keypress, without making it into a project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run an executable from a file manager such as Caja.

Say you have a file `hello.c` in the home directory `/home/User` containing a simple "hello, world" program with no GUI, such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

and the program is compiled by running `gcc -o hello hello.c` to generate an executable file `hello`.

To launch `hello` from Caja directly, you can provide a launcher that will launch a terminal and run the executable therein, or you can provide the executable with a simple GUI.

If you plan to use a launcher, then before doing anything else (unless you've already done this previously), it would be best to open a terminal, go to Preferences, add a new profile called e.g. "HoldOpen", and set "When command exits" on that profile's "Command" tab to "Hold the terminal open". Otherwise, the terminal will open, run the program, and close before you can see any results when launching from a launcher.

Then create a launcher for the `hello` program. A launcher is just a text file with a `.desktop` extension; conceptually, it's something like a Windows shortcut. The `.desktop` extension is not shown when the file appears in Caja, but it is visible in a directory listing in a terminal. A simple launcher for the purpose which should be saved as `hello.desktop` is:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=hello
Comment=
Exec=mate-terminal --profile=HoldOpen -e "/home/User/hello"
Icon=
Path=
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
```

A launcher can be written by hand, or (as the one above was) generated by right-clicking on the Desktop, selecting "Create Launcher...", and filling in at least the "Name" and "Command" boxes (the latter corresponding to the "Exec" key).

Double-clicking on the launcher file in Caja should launch `hello` in its own terminal and display its output therein.

Note that the "Terminal" key is set to "false" because it's actually mate-terminal that is being run, with `hello` being run in mate-terminal.

Also note that if you use gnome-terminal rather than mate-terminal, you may need to add a couple of newlines before "hello, world" to be able to see the output in the terminal.

For more info on launchers, see the Freedesktop.org [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/).

An alternative that allows running the program in Caja directly by double-clicking without need for a launcher is to use the Zenity application to generate GUI dialog boxes as needed, thereby providing the program with a simple GUI. You should be able to install Zenity by running `sudo apt-get install zenity`. Then, , you can replace stdio the printf statement in the hello.c program with stdlib and a system call to display a dialog box:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
system("zenity --info --title='Hello' --text='hello, world'");
}
```

See `man zenity` for more info on the Zenity application.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I reinstalled Mint as Cinnamon (so it's Nemo now not Caja) but I adapted what you advise, without success. The `hello.desktop` file reports "There was an error launching the application." I then made a launcher on the desktop filling in the two simple fields (name and executable) but I get the same error. The exact same path when typed into the terminal does run the program. Nemo differs from Caja in that it won't even recognise `hello` as being an executable. It says "The file hello has no known program associated with it" despite its first three bytes being `ELF`.

Comment: With regard to the error when using a launcher, make sure the path to your `hello` file has no spaces in it. Unfortunately, passing a path with spaces to either mate-terminal or gnome-terminal via the `-e` option (or the synonymous `--command` option) causes an error, even when the path is enclosed in quotes. A path with spaces can be used, but escaped double-quotes would need to be included, as e.g. `"\"/home/User 1/hello\""`.

Comment: Thanks for that, there were no spaces but I tried with and without enclosing quotes anway. I used the dialog provided by the Create Launcher tool in that case, and was able to edit the launcher afterwards.  (I would not use double-quotes within any filename, although a few have a single-quote for the apostrophe in a song title, but in such a case I would refer to it by *enclosing* in double-quotes.)

Comment: Pre-post tests were on a 64-bit non-Mint system with Caja and both Gnome & Mate Terminals. I retested both alternatives on 32-bit Mint 18.1 Serena \w Mate 1.16.0, Caja 1.16.6, and Mate Terminal; both worked on that as well. (The only difference from the pre-post tests was adding `system("sleep 0.5");` following the `printf` statement with the launcher version; without it, the launcher worked but the terminal didn't show the output; it seems the antique machine being used was too slow to update the screen properly.) Perhaps running on Mint 19.x gives different results.

Comment: I installed Mint Cinnamon Tricia 19.3 on an ancient x64 dual core machine, as a trial before I commit my main machine, which is Windows 7. For now I am OK with running my little utilities from a terminal. I had thought I was just missing a simple switch to enable a file manager to run an executable, rather than having to set up a launcher for every little thing I want to run. Later on when I make something more substantial, I'll need to research the proper way to install software.